# JQuery UI Sortable horizontal list has extra space

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, horizontallist

Here is my first question on StackOverflow!

Using JQuery UI, I want to build two sortable lists, the send list being displayed vertically, and the receive list horizontally. The receive list already has some values in it.

My problem is there's a little space between items already in the receive list, that don't appear when the user adds others items from the send list. It's not a blocking issue, but it sure doesn't look very professional...

I checked all the CSS properties, and all LI are the same. I really have no idea what to do...

Here is the code (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5gwfkkp/):

HTML

```
<ul id="receive">
    <li>un</li>
    <li>deux</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul id="send">
    <li>trois</li>
    <li>quatre</li>
    <li>cinq</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#receive li {
       display:inline-block !important;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
 $("#send").sortable({
    connectWith: '#receive',
 });

$("#receive").sortable();
$("#receive").disableSelection();

$("#receive li").addClass("ui-widget-content");
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: You could put the `#receive li { margin: 0 5px 0 0; float: left; }` This seems to fix the issue of added item being 'glued' to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried without the float option, but it added an extra space to the items already here. I tried your solution in the Fiddle, but strangely, whith float:left, I can't drop items in #receive anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. When you `float:left` the list items, the `ul` doesn't render as a block.

This will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/t5gwfkkp/2/

```
<ul id="receive">
    <li>un</li>
    <li>deux</li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul id="send">
    <li>trois</li>
    <li>quatre</li>
    <li>cinq</li>
</ul>

#receive li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden
}

#send {
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: Works great !! Thanks a lot.
Out of curiosity, have you any idea why I had this issue in the first place ?

Comment: `inline-block` elements just have this white space 'issue' because they are inline elements after all. This is just my guess tho... Oh and you can upvote if you want as well :)

Comment: I did, but since I just registered to StackOverflow, my votes are not yet public. Thank again tho :)